# Android Memory Discrepancy

Tags: android, memory

My phone states that the app that I've been working on uses 203.3 MB of memory (It's always the same amount). This seems like a huge amount, but I've never gotten an OutOfMemory error. The actual memory that gets observed in the Monitor is ~ 40 MB. I can't seem to figure out where 203.3 is coming from. Why is there this huge discrepancy between the two? Should I be worried about other phones getting OOM errors? Do I have a leak somewhere?

[Memory Usage For All Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7QbB.jpg)

[Memory Usage from Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYN6m.png)

Comment: Are you sure that's memory (RAM) and not disk space (storage)?  ANd where are those numbers from, because I've never seen a layout like that in stock Android.  Some app you got off the play store?

Comment: It's stock on my S7 and called "Usage Manager"

Comment: Hmm.  Well, my opinion of Samsung's programming is pretty low, so I wouldn't be surprised if it was just wrong.  But "Usage" doesn't necessarily mean RAM.  Are you sure it isn't disk usage?  45MB is just around where my Messenger app is for disk usage (mine is 40MB, which means my phone is newer or you text more).

Comment: I had face the same problem. My asset folder were containing the big files that made my app big in size. Check your asset folder or other res folder for big files(like media files or anything else).

Comment: Looking at the storage data the app is 3 MB, Data is 5 MB and cache is 20 MB.

Comment: And the more I look at it, the more I think Usage Manager is a liar. Just not sure how/why. Pretty sure it's not showing storage as it offers to kill running apps and shows the MB they are using.